# XmlReader - only read "child xpath axis"

Tags: .net, ixmlserializable

Hello I have xml that has nested elements that are the same. It's recursive (joy!)

Like so:

```xml
<MyRoot>
  <Record Name="Header" >
    <Field Type="Pattern" Expression=";VR_PANEL_ID,\s+" />
    <Field Name="PanelID" Type="Pattern" Expression="\d+"/>
    <Field Type="Pattern" Expression="," />
    <Field Name="ProductionDateTime" Type="Pattern" Expression=".+?(?=,)" />
    <Field Type="Pattern" Expression=".+?" />
  </Record>
  <Record Name="Body" MaxOccurs="0">
    <Record Name="Command"  Compositor="Choice">
      <Record Name="Liquid Status" >
        <Record Name="Header" >
          <Field Type="Pattern" Expression="i30100" />
          <Field  Name="DateTime" Type="Pattern" Expression="\d{10}"/>
        </Record>
        <Record Name="Data" MinOccurs="0" MaxOccurs="0">
          <Field Name="DeviceNum" Type="Pattern" Expression="\d\d" />
          <Field Name="Status" Type="Pattern" Expression="\d{4}" />
        </Record>
      </Record>
    </Record>
    <Record Name="Footer" >
      <Field Type="Pattern" Expression="&amp;&amp;[A-F0-9]" />
    </Record>
  </Record>
</MyRoot>
```

Once the `XmlReader` is positioned over `MyRoot`, how can I just loop thru only the direct children of `MyRoot` (in this case, `<Record Name="Header" >` and `<Record Name="Body" MaxOccurs="0">`). I am delegating reading the xml for those nodes to another class, recursively.

Before considering duplicate questions, make sure the OP isn't asking about grand-children or some other node-set besides the xpath axis of `children`. I could not find an exact match for this question and the `XmlReader` seems to want to go depth first all the time.

What I would love to do is hand off the `XmlReader` and have the child object that is consuming the child xml hand it back to me pointed right where it needs to be to get the next child. That would be sweet.

Comment: Are you restricted to use the `XmlReader`?

Comment: @VMAtm, I am implementing `IXmlSerializable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked. Sorry it's not 100% generic, but it might give you an idea:

```
public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
    ReadAttributes(this, reader);
    reader.Read(); //advance
    switch (reader.Name) {
        case "Record":
        case "Field":
            break;
        default:
            reader.MoveToContent(); //skip other nodes
            break;
    }

    if (reader.Name == "Record") {
        do {
            LexicalRecordType Record = new LexicalRecordType();
            Record.ReadXml(reader);
            Records.Add(Record);
            //.Read() 
        } while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("Record")); //get next record
    } else if (reader.Name == "Field") {
        do {
            LexicalField Field = Deserialize(reader.ReadOuterXml, typeof(LexicalField));
            Add(Field);
        } while (reader.Name == "Field");
    }
}

public void ReadAttributes(object NonSerializableObject, System.Xml.XmlReader XmlReader)
{
    XmlReader.MoveToContent();
    for (int Index = 0; Index <= XmlReader.AttributeCount - 1; Index++) {
        XmlReader.MoveToAttribute(Index);
        PropertyInfo PropertyInfo = NonSerializableObject.GetType.GetProperty(XmlReader.LocalName);
        PropertyInfo.SetValue(NonSerializableObject, ConvertAttribute(XmlReader.Value, PropertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
    }
    XmlReader.MoveToContent();
}
```